# Why does type casting from "int" to "float" cut my value in half?

Tags: c++, casting

I was testing out type casting in C++ today after reviewing a past quiz and can't for the life of me figure out why my 'x' value changes from 9 to 4.5000 in the following code.

```
int main(){
    int x = 9, y = 2;
    float z;
    z = (float)x/(float)y;
    printf("\n%f", z);
    printf("\n%f", x);
    printf("\n%d", x);
}
```

Outputs

```
4.5000
4.5000
9
```

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior.  It is UB to give `printf` a variable type that doesn't match the format.  You are giving `printf` an `int`, but fooling it by saying it is a `float` type.

Comment: Turn up the warning level on your compiler, it will find this sort of error automatically for you. For gcc, use `-Wformat` (which is included in `-Wall`).

Comment: Assembly for anyone that wants to view it: http://pastebin.com/tgNUYxgK

Answer (score 8):

The `printf` function is expecting a `float` to be on the stack (because of `%f`) and you've only provided an `int`.

You need to cast `x` to a `float` in that case:

```
printf("\n%f", (float)x);
```

Comment: It's actually expecting a `double` (to which a `float` argument is automatically promoted in this case).

Answer (score 6):

In `printf("\n%f", x)` with an `int x`, you are not *casting* `x` to `float` - you're *assuming* it's a float. It's like handing a firefighter a stick of butter and telling him it's a fire extinguisher - won't work right.

In order to cast, you either have to assign the value to a cast-compatible variable:

```
float floatX = x;
printf("\n%f", floatX);
```

or use the cast operator:

```
printf("\n%f", (float)x);
```

Comment: @Brandon no, not even close

Comment: @Brandon For many implementations, the printf function has to walk the stack, and relies on the *format string*, not the trailing arguments after the format string, to figure out what is what on the stack.  So right there, you are in trouble...

Comment: @Brandon: It can't cast it because it doesn't know that it isn't a double. All the arguments in C are on stack, typeless, and `va_arg`'s job is to make them presentable (i.e. properly counted and typed). `va_arg(args, double)` just says "here, there's `double`-worth of bytes on the stack, get them and let's say they are one `double`". It does not recalculate them as a cast would. If there *isn't* a double on the stack, you get a butter stick.

Answer (score 0):

It is not cutting your X in half. look at the code below it still prints 4.5

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int x = 9, y = 2;
    float z;
    z = (float)x/(float)y;
    x = 15;
    printf("\n%f", z);
    printf("\n%f", x);
    printf("\n%d", x);
}
```

this prints:

```
4.500000
4.500000
15
```

May be it has to do internally with how floats and ints are stored on stack. Its fishy because its the first float value that gets stored. If I change the code to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int x = 11, y = 2;
    float z;
    z = (float)x/(float)y;
    x = 15;
    printf("\n%f", z);
    printf("\n%f", x);
    printf("\n%d", x);
}
```

the output is

```
5.500000
5.500000
15
```

If you dont print the variable `z`, then the output becomes

```
0.000000
15
```

So may be it has to do with the order of printing.

Comment: There is no guarantee the program even finishes the second `printf` without crashing.  UB.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie if the second printf crashes how can it print the third one?

Comment: It won't print it.  Undefined behavior means exactly that -- anything can happen, including crash.

Comment: I don't know how else to explain it any more simpler than *anything can happen*.  If  I write a program that declares an array, I go beyond the boundaries of that array, and the program "works", does it mean it really works, or is the behavior undefined?  C++ isn't Java or other languages where you're *guaranteed* a "bad" program crashes.  That's not how it works with C++.

Comment: Anything can happen, and that *may* coincidentally include the scenario that you wish to have happen. But there are no guarantees that it will do the same thing next time, that it will do the same thing on a different compiler, different computer, or architecture.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I know the program is wrong. But what I am trying to find here is why is there a pattern. A perfect "undefined behaviour" should mean that the output should not be deterministic. But here it follows that if you print a float variable with %f and then an int variable with %f then what gets printed is the same float variable. this is not "undefined" because it follows a pattern. I want to know  why this happens.

Comment: @VivekVK And if you change the compiler options such as optimizations, what if the behavior now becomes different?  You then become a dog trying to chase its own tail attempting to figure out the pattern.  Just recognize it as UB and leave it at that.

Comment: It can be deterministic - one compiler can consistently give the same result. For example, `a = (a++) + (++a)` will consistently give the same result on the same compiler with same options, but you'd be a fool to rely on that pattern holding on another one. "Undefined" just means that the Standard doesn't tell compilers what to do in that case. The compilers can pick an option and stick with it, they can crash, they can let the executable crash, they can activate the USB fridge and give you a banana if they want to and you have a USB fridge (not that I know any compiler that does this.)

Comment: If you want to find out what code the compiler *actually* generated, and in turn find the reason for the behaviour you observe, then either (1) ask your compiler to generate an assembly code listing, or (b) run the code under an assembly level debugger.